# Disable getting app review from user if the user has already rated

Tags: swift, storekit

I have a one question and I need one suggestion

I use these codes to get app review from user, it's written in the app delegate and count how many times that user open the app.

```
    if currentLaunchingCount == 10 || currentLaunchingCount == 20 || currentLaunchingCount == 30 || currentLaunchingCount == 40 || currentLaunchingCount == 50 || currentLaunchingCount == 60 || currentLaunchingCount == 70 || currentLaunchingCount == 80 || currentLaunchingCount == 90 || currentLaunchingCount == 100 {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    }
```

It works fine, but I don't know, if user has already rated, it will appear again or not? if it will, how can I disable it.

I need a suggestion as well, I really don't like my code about it, it's too long, how can I make it shorter? I want to say when `currentLaunchingCount` is equal to 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 ask for reviewing.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your app delegate should definitely not contain this code. Very quickly, you'll have a massive app delegate that does way too many things and gets way too complex. Create a `UserRatingPromper` object, put a method on it like `func didStartApp()` (that increments the counter, and does whatever else is necessary to prompt a user for a rating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple handles the ["has this person already rated"](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/system-capabilities/ratings-and-reviews/) portion for you.

> If the user hasn't already given feedback, the system displays an
>   in-app prompt that asks for a rating and an optional written review.

<strike>Regarding your if statement, use a modulus (`%`):</strike>

`if currentLaunchingCount > 0 && currentLaunchingCount % 10 == 0 { ... }`

Updated from comment by Alexander (today I learned...)

`0 < currentLaunchingCount.isMultiple && currentLaunchingCount.isMultiple(of: 10)`

Regarding the comment about not using logic, I'll first quote Apple from the HIG:

> Don’t be a pest. Repeated rating prompts can be irritating, and may
>   even negatively influence the user’s opinion of your app. Allow at
>   least a week or two between rating requests and only prompt again
>   after the user has demonstrated additional engagement with your app.

This is purely subjective and feel free to ignore me. However, they are correct in that you should give your user some time to get into your app (assuming this is relevant). Assuming they have used it x times, then find a good place where the user is likely to be pleased with your app and then ask.

If you throw up a prompt as soon as I launch your app, then I hope you like 1 stars.

There is some additional logic around showing prompts (most importantly, that your app can only present 3x a year) and as alluded by rmaddy in his comment, Apple does processing in the background that we are unaware of, which will also affect showing your prompt. Not having an Apple badge, I cannot speak to *what* that is....

Comment: To clarify the point being made in the link, just call `requestReview()` every time your app runs. Apple will do what it thinks is best. No need for any logic on your part.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I didn't find anything in that page related that Apple handle it when someone has already rated

Comment: @Jon Click the [Requesting App Store Reviews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/requesting_app_store_reviews) link. It takes you to a sample app. The description goes into a bit more detail.

Comment: Using modulo for checking for multiples is "outdated" now. `0 < currentLaunchingCount.isMultiple && currentLaunchingCount.isMultiple(of: 10)`

Comment: Adjusted most of the answer & incorporated all of the comments